# Conditional Probability with ESP!

Tags: probability, statistics

In a group of ten people, one has ESP and the other nine are completely ordinary. You select one of these people at random and ask that person to predict the results of five tosses of a fair coin. They get all of them right. What is the probability that the person you chose is the one with ESP?

I know it's not as simple as 1/10. In order to guess the results of five tosses of a fair coin, the odds is .5^5=.03125.  How can I incorporate these two facts together to produce the probability

Comment: Use bayes' rule and conditional probabilities: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem

Comment: would it be something like (9/10)(.5^6) which is the odds of selecting a normal person and the odds of getting all five right

Comment: You are assuming that having ESP is not ordinary.

Comment: @Gerry: It's not ordinary. If perception is the information processed from our senses whatever they may be (including, but not limited to, being able to predict coin flip outcomes), extrasensory perception means that the individual is able to obtain information about the world not through their senses. [I mean, seriously the "five senses" thing is really bogus. If that is the case, everyone with a sense of time has an extrasensory perception... So at least all the living people!]

Comment: @Asaf, sure, but, what if *everybody* can obtain information about the world, other than through their senses?

Comment: @Gerry: Like through the internet? :-)

Comment: @Asaf, we've got to stop meeting like this.

Answer (score 1):

As Ragnar mentioned, using the Bayes rule will provide the answer.

Let ESP denote the event that the ESP person gets chosen, and let O be the event that an ordinary person gets chosen(which is equivalent to ESP compliment). And let T be the event that the results of five tosses of a fair coin are all correctly predicted. Then, we are to find $P(ESP|T)$.

Now by Bayes rule, 
\begin{align}
P(ESP|T)&=\frac{P(T|ESP)P(ESP)}{P(T)}\\
        &=\frac{P(T|ESP)P(ESP)}{P(T|ESP)P(ESP)+P(T|O)P(O)}
\end{align}
Now plug in these values:
$P(T|ESP)=1$ (assuming the ESP person can correctly predict the tosses somehow);
\begin{align}
P(ESP)&=\frac1{10}\\
P(T|O)&=\left(\frac 15\right)^5=.03125\\
P(O)&=\frac9{10}
\end{align}

This will give the probability $P(ESP|T)=0.78049$